# Chromedriver unexpectedly exited in Colab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I have been using chrome driver in google colab for the last 4 month. Nothing has changed in my code but suddenly colab has started throwing errors.

error message :
`WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6`

I know many questions had been asked related to this but, none of them worked for me. I wonder if any of you faced such error recently in google colab.

my code :

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

`webdriver.Chrome()` need to be passed `service` and optionally `options` parameter.
Here you passing a dummy `'chromedriver'` string instead of `service`
Try this:

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
webdriver_service = Service('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it didn't work. one detail, the exact same code was working before this week. so, the parameter 'chromedriver' cannot be the problem here.